# collapse specific column and row within a group as a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to collapse rows and join column in a group. Not sure, how to collapse 2 columns in specific combination.

Tried the following

```
df1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    agency = toString(unique(agency)),
    bucket = toString(unique(bucket))
  ) %>%
  dplyr::distinct()
```

Not sure, how to create the combination while pasting the column values.

data input

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1.1, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3), time = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), restriction = c("18+", "18+", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), county = c("Checked", "Checked", "Checked", 
"Checked", "Checked", "Checked"), zip_code = c("Checked", "Checked", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), age = c("Checked", "Checked", NA, NA, NA, NA
), delay = c("2 months", "2 months", "1 month", "1 month", "1 month", 
"1 month"), agency = c("SA", "Australia", "Africa", "Africa", 
"USA", "USA"), agency_response = c("Checked", "Checked", "Checked", 
"Checked", "Checked", "Checked"), bucket = c("DC", "DC", "Marvel", 
"Pixar", "Marvel", "Pixar"), bucket_response = c("Checked", "Checked", 
"Checked", "Checked", "Checked", "Checked")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

expected output

```
 > df2
   ID time restriction  county zip_code     age    delay                agency.bucket
1 1.0    M         18+ Checked  Checked Checked 2 months                        SA:DC
2 1.1    M         18+ Checked  Checked Checked 2 months               Australia : DC
3 3.3    M         N/A Checked     <NA>    <NA>  1 month Africa: Marvel & USA : Pixar
```

Comment: Why Africa:Marvel and not Africa:Pixar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `summarise` to collapse by `pasting` the `unique` values of agency and bucket. For the other columns, use `across` to get the `unique` value.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(time:delay, unique),
            agency.bucket = paste(unique(agency), unique(bucket), sep = ":", collapse = ", "))
```

```r
   ID time restriction  county zip_code     age    delay            agency.bucket
1 1.0    M         18+ Checked  Checked Checked 2 months                    SA:DC
2 1.1    M         18+ Checked  Checked Checked 2 months             Australia:DC
3 3.3    M         N/A Checked     <NA>    <NA>  1 month Africa:Marvel, USA:Pixar
```

Comment: Thank you. To summarise, would like to include all the data columns, is it possible? I have too many columns to select

Comment: yes, include them in the first argument of `across`